# MySQLl key-value store ordering with specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, key-value-store

I have the following structure:

```
+----------+--------+---------------------+
| id| gr_id| name   | value               |
+----------+--------+---------------------+
| 1  |  11 | name   | Burro               |
| 2  |  11 | submit | 2019/05/10          |
| 3  |  11 | date   | 2019/05/17          |   
| 4  |  12 | name   | Ajax                |
| 5  |  12 | submit | 2019/05/10          |
| 6  |  12 | date   | 2019/05/18          | 
+----------+--------+---------------------+
```

I have to order it by the date(if the name is date), from highest to lowest date, also it has to keep the groups (gr_id) without mixing the elments.

The desired result would look like this:

```
+----------+--------+---------------------+
| id| gr_id| name   | value               |
+----------+--------+---------------------+
| 4  |  12 | name   | Ajax                |
| 5  |  12 | submit | 2019/05/10          |
| 6  |  12 | date   | 2019/05/18          |   
| 1  |  11 | name   | Burro               |
| 2  |  11 | submit | 2019/05/10          |
| 3  |  11 | date   | 2019/05/17          | 
+----------+--------+---------------------+
```

How can i implement this?

Comment: Did you mean for the id values to not move with the rest of the values?

Comment: sorry i made a mistake,i corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to associate the group ordering criteria with all the elements of the group. You can do it through a subquery, or a join.

Subquery version:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT gr_id, value as `date` FROM t WHERE `name` = 'date') AS grpOrder
INNER JOIN t ON grpOrder.gr_id = t.gr_id
ORDER BY grpOrder.`date`
, CASE `name` 
   WHEN 'name' THEN 1 
   WHEN 'submit' THEN 2
   WHEN 'date' THEN 3
   ELSE 4
 END
```

Join version:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t AS t1
INNER JOIN AS t2 ON t1.gr_id = t2.gr_id AND t2.`name` = 'date'
ORDER BY t2.value
, CASE t1.`name` 
   WHEN 'name' THEN 1 
   WHEN 'submit' THEN 2
   WHEN 'date' THEN 3
   ELSE 4
 END
```

Comment: thank you very much your help,just one more question do you know a good resource to master my mysql like you?

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for the compliment. College introduced me to the basics, and over ten years of work as built on that. I don't really know of any good online resources for learning, but I am the type of person that can generally read documentation and figure stuff out from there, so would suggest MySQL's official online documentation as a good place to start. Otherwise, I find lurking around here on topics I am less than familiar with is a good way to get informally acquainted with those topics.

Comment: thank you for your well detailed answer. Sometimes i feel i have no sense to figure out task. I know the basics but havent need to use in specific ways probably thats an issue for me. Thank you for opening my eyes